How can I secure pergola posts on condo deck without damaging the deck?
We’re considering installing a pergola or gazebo on our patio deck of our condo (top floor condo in Northern California). Our condo restrictions do not allow us to drill into the decking or the side of the building, and so we’re hoping to brainstorm an idea for safely and securely installing a gazebo or pergola.
The idea that seems most promising would be to set the four posts of the structure in plant pots/boxes and concrete them into those boxes (added benefit that, if drainage is solved for, plants could also be added to those boxes).
Are there any suggestions for other options or whether this solution is advisable? Again, it’s nonnegotiable to secure it to the decking. In the four years we’ve lived there, our umbrella (weighted with sand) has blown over, but has never been uplifted.

How much insurance coverage can you afford. Picture your gazebo falling off your deck…

Or adding enough weight to hold it down against wind forces that it goes through the deck via gravity... Must be some extra seismic concerns from putting big weights on the deck a local engineer would be familiar with as well.

This feels like an XY question, assuming a particular (difficult) solution rather than addressing the need. WHY do you want "a gazebo", and will other shelter do? i'd consider an awning, maybe with flexible plastic sides, rather than a solid structure. Mostly stuff that can't hurt anyone if it blows off, less weight...

That's a tough one. Technically, in condominiums, any external decks or patios are collectively owned by the condo association that runs the building or complex, even though the patio or balcony may be accessible only from a single condo unit.
